# How to access user added metadata in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I create a dataframe and added some metadata to a column in it

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

from pyspark.sql import column

df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]}))

df=df.withColumn('a',col('a').alias('a',metadata={'numClasses':2}))
```

How can I access the metadata added to the column `a`?
I tried looking at `df.schema` but it does not get updated with the metadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following way.

```
print(df.schema['a'].metadata['numClasses'])
```